# Pylint showing invalid variable name in output

Tags: python, pylint

I made a simple python script to post data on a website.

```
#Imports

url_to_short = sys.argv[1]

post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data = {'longUrl': url_to_short}
post_data = json.dumps(data)

req = urllib2.Request(post_url, post_data, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

if resp.getcode() == 200:  
    content = json.loads(resp.read())

#Other stuff
```

Now I thought lets check my script for coding standards with `pylint` tool.

My `pylint` output is as follows:

```
************* Module post
C:  1,0: Missing docstring
C:  6,0: Invalid name "url_to_short" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C:  8,0: Invalid name "post_url" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)
C:  9,0: Invalid name "headers" (should match (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$)

# Other stuff
```

Now, my question is why `pylint` is showing my variable names as `Invalid name`. Is naming variable this way a wrong coding convention.

My [complete pylint output](http://pastie.org/3994703).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As your code is not contained in a class or function it is expecting those variables to be [constants](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) and as such they should be uppercase.

You can read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for further information.

Comment: More especially the [naming conventions part](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) of PEP8

Comment: So, is it always necessary that if i write such small code snippets they should be inside a class.

Comment: I wouldn't write it in a class, I would just put it in a function definition instead which is good practice for code re-use too.

Comment: Pep 8 doesn't prohibit global variables... It would be dumb to do so because python is often used to write short scripts. This is obviously a case of pylint putting in restrictions that don't exist in PEP 8.

Comment: @catphive pylint doesn't prohibit them either, it just requires that they follow the ALL_CAPS naming convention.

Comment: @Kroltan In the "global variables" section, PEP8 says that global variables should be formatted like functions, so ALL_CAPS is wrong. My guess is that it is hard for pylint to check if a variable is used as a constant or a variable, so it defaults to only allowing module-level constants since global variables are generally discouraged any way and you can disable pylint on a case-by-case basis for them.

Comment: @catphive Restriction is brilliant - to write every program in same coding standard.

Comment: @Kroltan: And what happens if those variables aren't constants?

Answer (score 27):

EDIT: As others have mentioned, pylint expects that global variables should be UPPERCASE. If the warnings really bother you, you can circumvent them by wrapping small snippets like this in a `main()`-function and then use the `if __name__ == "__main__"`-convention. Or if you care, you can modify the regular expressions that pylint uses to validate variable names.

From the [developers](http://www.logilab.org/4736) of Pylint.

> In this case Pylint is telling me that those variables appear to be constants and should be all UPPERCASE. This rule is in fact a naming convention that is specific to the folks at Logilab who created Pylint. That is the way they have chosen to name those variables. You too can create your own in-house naming conventions but for the purpose of this tutorial, we want to stick to the PEP-8 standard. In this case, the variables I declared should follow the convention of all lowercase. The appropriate rule would be something like: "should match [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$". Notice the lowercase letters in the regular expression (a-z versus A-Z)

You can test it by running:
`pylint --const-rgx='[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$' x.py`

Answer (score 7):

It's because `url_to_short` is declared in the global namespace, and pylint requires global variables (e.g. constants) to be named `ALL_UPPERCASE`.
Therefore it checks whether your variable name matches the regex used for globals, which is: `(([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$` (note the `A-Z` ranges). Hence the `Invalid name` error.