# typing disables pylint invalid name

Tags: python, pylint

When I run pylint on a code like this one:

```
some_variable = 3

def do_something():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

I get:

```
file.py:2:0: C0103: Constant name "some_variable" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
```

However, if I use typing to specify the type of the variable:

```
some_variable: int = 3
```

The invalid-name is not triggered anymore.
Furthermore, I can use any name, like `SOMEVARIABLE`, `someVariable` or `SOME_VARIABLE` and it won't be triggered.

Why does this happen?

Comment: If you believe this is a bug, feel free to open an issue on their open-source project: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint

Answer (score -1):

the variables that are not contained in a class or a function are expected to be constants and need to be in upper case. check here PEP 8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: may have been answered here some years back <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815549/pylint-showing-invalid-variable-name-in-output>

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question. This answer confirms that a linting message should be triggered. But the question mentions clearly that, when there is a type annotation, no message is triggered.